# XMLHTTPREQUEST Problem while i append to dive in html

Tags: javascript, api, xmlhttprequest

Hei Friends I just start to learn XMLHttpRequest
I write this code its work on console.log but when I append it to HTML it shows me Object Object i know its object but I wanna show the data inside the object in HTML  HELP PLEASE

```
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    myRequest.onload = function () {
      if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        resolve(JSON.parse(myRequest.responseText));
      } else {
        reject(Error(this.statusText));
      }
    };

    myRequest.open("GET", apiURL, true);
    // send request to API
    myRequest.send();
  });
};

apiGenerator("https://random-data-api.com/api/stripe/random_stripe").then(
  (resulit) => {
    console.log(resulit);
    let newElement = document.createElement("div");
    let elementText = document.createTextNode(resulit);
    newElement.appendChild(elementText);
    document.body.appendChild(...newElement);
  },
  (error) => console.log(error)
);
```

Comment: Because `result` is the result *object*.

Comment: Yes but how to take the data from inside of the object and show them in the div i hope you get my question